# Reassign a function attribute makes it 'unreachable'

Tags: python, function-attributes

I have a simple little decorator, that caches results from function calls in a `dict` as a function attribute.

```
from decorator import decorator
def _dynamic_programming(f, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        f.cache[args]
    except KeyError:
        f.cache[args] = f(*args, **kwargs)
    return f.cache[args]

def dynamic_programming(f):
    f.cache = {}
    return decorator(_dynamic_programming, f)
```

I now want to add the possibility to empty the cache. So I change the `dynamic_programming()` function like this:

```
def dynamic_programming(f):
    f.cache = {}
    def clear():
        f.cache = {}
    f.clear = clear
    return decorator(_dynamic_programming, f)
```

Now let's assume I use this little thing to implement a Fibonacci number function:

```
@dynamic_programming
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

>>> fib(4)
5
>>> fib.cache
{(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (3,): 3, (4,): 5}
```

But now when I clear the cache something weird happens:

```
>>> fib.clear()
>>> fib.cache
{(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (3,): 3, (4,): 5}
```

Or (with a new Python kernel running) do it the other way round:

```
>>> fib.clear()
>>> fib(4)
5
>>> fib.cache
{}
```

Why is the cache somehow not 'reachable' after the first access to it, i.e. not changing when calling `clear()` after a call or a call after a `clear()`?

(Btw. I know a solution to clear the cache correctly: calling `f.cache.clear()` instead of assigning `{}` to it works as expected. I'm merely interested in the *reason* why the assigning solution fails.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the `decorator` module. If you add some `print` statements to your decorator:

```
from decorator import decorator
def _dynamic_programming(f, *args, **kwargs):
    print "Inside decorator", id(f.cache)
    try:
        f.cache[args]
    except KeyError:
        f.cache[args] = f(*args, **kwargs)
    return f.cache[args]

def dynamic_programming(f):
    f.cache = {}
    print "Original cache", id(f.cache)
    def clear():
        f.cache = {}
        print "New cache", id(f.cache)
    f.clear = clear
    return decorator(_dynamic_programming, f)

@dynamic_programming
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print fib(4)
print id(fib.cache)
fib.clear()
print id(fib.cache)
print fib(10)
print id(fib.cache)
```

It outputs (duplicate lines skipped):

```
Original cache 139877501744024
Inside decorator 139877501744024
5
139877501744024
New cache 139877501802208
139877501744024
Inside decorator 139877501802208
89
139877501744024
```

As you can see, the `cache` inside the decorator changes according the the clear function. However, the `cache` accessed from `__main__` does not change. Printing the `cache` outside and inside the decorator give a clearer picture (again, duplicates skipped):

```
Inside decorator {}
Inside decorator {(1,): 1}
Inside decorator {(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (1,): 1}
Inside decorator {(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (3,): 3, (1,): 1}
5
Outside {(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (3,): 3, (1,): 1, (4,): 5}
Inside decorator {}
Inside decorator {(1,): 1}
Inside decorator {(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (1,): 1}
Inside decorator {(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (3,): 3, (1,): 1}
Inside decorator {(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (3,): 3, (1,): 1, (4,): 5}
Inside decorator {(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (3,): 3, (4,): 5, (5,): 8}
Inside decorator {(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (3,): 3, (4,): 5, (5,): 8, (6,): 13}
Inside decorator {(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (3,): 3, (4,): 5, (5,): 8, (6,): 13, (7,): 21}
Inside decorator {(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (8,): 34, (3,): 3, (4,): 5, (5,): 8, (6,): 13, (7,): 21}
Inside decorator {(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (8,): 34, (3,): 3, (9,): 55, (4,): 5, (5,): 8, (6,): 13, (7,): 21}
89
Outside {(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (3,): 3, (1,): 1, (4,): 5}
```

As you can see, the inside changes are not echoed on the outside. The problem is that inside [the `decorator` module](http://code.google.com/p/micheles/source/browse/decorator/src/decorator.py#107), there is the line (inside the class it used to make the decorator):

```
self.dict = func.__dict__.copy()
```

And then [later](http://code.google.com/p/micheles/source/browse/decorator/src/decorator.py#130):

```
func.__dict__ = getattr(self, 'dict', {})
```

So basically, the `__dict__` on the outside is different from the `__dict__` on the inside. This means that:

- The `__dict__` is copied (not referenced) by the decorator
- When the `cache` changes, it changes the inside `__dict__`, not the outside `__dict__`
- Therefore, the `cache` used by the `_dynamic_programming` is cleared, but you cannot see that from the outside, as the decorator's `__dict__` is still pointing to the old `cache` (as you can see above, as the inside `cache` updates, while the outside `cache` remains the same)

So, to summarise, it's a problem with the `decorator` module.

Comment: My longest post yet on SO, by the looks of it ... :)

Answer (score 3):

so @matsjoyce's answer is very interesting and in-depth and i know you already have the solution, but i always find it a little clearer to write my own decorators:

```
def dynamic_programming(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return wrapper.cache[args]            
        except KeyError:
            res = wrapper.cache[args] = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return res
    wrapper.cache = {}
    wrapper.clear = wrapper.cache.clear
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Good point. With problems like this, it helps to see any oddities without digging into a module's source...